# Doubt about the derivation of Liénard-Wiechert Potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

When deriving the Lienard-Wiechert Potentials, there is one step that you need to perform:
$$
\nabla_{\mathbf r}|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s(t_r)|
$$
Where $t_r$ is:
$$
t_r = t - \frac{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s(t_r)|}{c}
$$
$\mathbf r$, is the position where you are calculating the field and $\mathbf r_s$ is the position of a particle. According to the [wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential), the result is the following:
$$
\nabla_{\mathbf r}|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s(t_r)| = \nabla_{\mathbf r} t_r \frac{d|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s(t_r)| }{d t_r} + \mathbf n_s = \frac{\mathbf n_s}{1-\boldsymbol \beta_s \cdot \mathbf n_s}
$$
Where:
$$
\mathbf n_s = \frac{\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|}
$$
$$
\boldsymbol{\beta_s} = \frac{\mathbf v_s}{c}
$$
I don't quite understand this result. How do you obtain this $\nabla_{\mathbf r}|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|$ from the retarded time? I assume it cames from the chain rule, but I cannot derive it by myself. Any hint?

Comment: The term $\nabla_{\mathbf r} t_r $ is equal to $-1/c$ times $\nabla_{\mathbf r}|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s(t_r)| $. This gives you a linear equation for such a gradient.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 But $|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s(t_r)|$, also depends on the retarded time. How would I do this?

Comment: basics's answer made explicit my hint.

Comment: You have to study this in a textbook. You have found out that Wikipedia is not much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that some problems could arise for a kind of circular dependence of the variables involved.
Let's get some partial results first and then put everything together:

- gradient of the retarded time $\nabla t_r(\mathbf{r}) = \nabla \left( t - \frac{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|}{c} \right)$, that from direct computation reads
  $$\nabla t_r = -\frac{1}{c} \nabla|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)| \ ,$$
  we don't need to manipulate this result further, so far, since the unknwon has appeared;
- gradient of the absolute value $|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|$, that by direct computation reads
  $$\begin{aligned} \nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)| & = \frac{1}{2 |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|} \nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|^2 = \\
  & = \frac{1}{2|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|} \, 2 \left[ \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r) - ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r) ) \cdot \frac{d \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)}{d t_r} \nabla t_r \right] = \\
  \end{aligned} \ .$$
- Using the epxression of the first point for $\nabla t_r$and defining $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \frac{\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|} $, and $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \frac{1}{c}\frac{d \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)}{d t_r}$, it should be not so hard to recast the last equation as
  $$\nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)| = \mathbf{\hat{n}}  + \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\beta} \, \nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|$$
- Eventually, solving for $\nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|$, we get the desired expression
  $$\nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)| = \frac{\mathbf{\hat{n}}}{1 - \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\beta}} \ .$$

That should provide a way to get the desired result.

---

**Edit 1. Required details about $\nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|^2.$** Direct calculation using Cartesian coordinates (for simplicity) gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\left\{ \nabla |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)|^2 \right\}_i & =  \partial_i \sum_k \left( r_k - r_k^s(t_r(r_j)) \right)^2 = \\
& = 2 \sum_k \left( \partial_i r_k - \partial_i r_k^s \right)  \left( r_k - r_k^s(t_r(r_j)) \right) = \\
& = 2 \sum_k \left( \delta_{ik} - \partial_{t_r} r_k^s \partial_i t_r(r_j) \right)  \left( r_k - r_k^s(t_r(r_j)) \right) = \\
& = 2 \left( r_i - r_k^s(t_i(r_j)) \right) - 2 \partial_i t_r(r_j) \sum_k \partial_{t_r} r_k^s \left( r_k - r_k^s(t_r(r_j)) \right) = \\
& = 2 \left\{ \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}^s - \nabla t_r \, \dfrac{d \mathbf{r}^s}{dt_r} \cdot ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}^s ) \right\}_i
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Sorry But I do not understand why $\nabla |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|^2 = 2 \left[ \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r) - ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t_r) ) \cdot \frac{d \mathbf{r}_s(t_r)}{d t_r} \nabla t_r \right]$? Could you explain it in depth please?

Comment: editing........

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Maybe is too much to ask, but there is any other derivation $\nabla |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_s|^2$, that do not involve the Einstein sumation convetion, or can be done directly in vector notation?

Comment: you're welcome. Glad to manage to be helpful sometimes

Comment: Isn't the sign in your detailed derivation different?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo you can do it, but it may be not so clear. Whenever I have a doubt (and thus often), if I can, I use Cartesian coordinates to prove vector identities or do computations

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @Emil typo. Thanks. Corrected. Try to have a look if it's ok now, or other corrections are needed

Comment: I'm not that experienced with actually computing in einstein notation so a bit too hard for me to proofread.